# How to use Apache Benchmark (ab) to login to a site

Tags: apache, benchmarking, load-testing

I am running a php based web application in Ubuntu platform. I want to perform load testing to 1000 concurrent users for the login process. (when correct username and password are provided, it will be directed to the home page).

I am using Apache Benchmark (ab) to do the load testing. I used this command  to load the login page alone.

```
    ab -n 1000 -c 1000 http://localhost/etsp/
```

How can I extend this command to test the login process? What I meant was, is there any way to provide username and password to this?

Any hint will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 15):

Look at the [man page for Apache Benchmark](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/ab.html) for the option that makes the most sense given your application:

- **HTTP Basic Authentication**
  You want the `-A` option to supply basic authentication credentials.
- **Cookie-Based Authentication**
  You want the `-C` option to supply the cookie name and value.
- **Form-based Authentication Trigger**
  You want the `-T` and `-p` options to specify a POST file and content type for that file. If it's a standard HTML form, the content type is probably going to be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. The file is going to contain the login form field name/value pairs encoded for the form submission. The Stack Overflow answer **[application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data?](//stackoverflow.com/questions/4007969/application-x-www-form-urlencoded-or-multipart-form-data)** has information about how to do this.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried "HTTP Basic Authentication"=>  ab -A Ron:Ron123 -n 1000 -c 1000 http://localhost/etsp/index.php/verifylogin/verify command. Is this the correct way?

Comment: If your PHP web site is using HTTP Basic Authentication for its authentication, then yes, that is a correct way to do it. Without knowing more details of your app's login process, I can't say whether that will be enough. That will test 1000 clients simultaneously issuing a single request which will send the username and password.

Comment: lower case -p (uppercase -P is for proxy auth)

Comment: @mikejonesey Thanks for picking that out. I've corrected it.

Answer (score 4):

You should use Cookie-based Authentication. Log in to your web site using browser and get cookie name and value.
From linux console execute something like this:

ab -C PHPSESSID=h9s0r2hbpuf91vt7ulvnurp300  -l -r -n 100 -c 10 -k -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate" http://localhost/some_path/your_page.php

From documentation
-C cookie-name=value
    Add a Cookie: line to the request. The argument is typically in the form of a name=value pair. This field is repeatable.

Comment: CSRF protection would stop this from working right?
 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery